# User/Manager document library

Tags: sharepoint-server

I've been assigned a task to create a SharePoint document library in which members of our team can upload documents to be seen by our manager. Each user can only view/open the documents they have uploaded (and that have been changed by the manager) and our manager can view/change all documents uploaded by users.

FYI I'm new to SharePoint and have read a couple of ideas on how to do this, but I'm not 100% sure. Any help will be very much appreciated :)

Comment: How many users are there? Do you have option to deploy code to achieve this?

Comment: @Unnie It for a team of a bout 50 people and no code can be used. There must be some security settings available to do this

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using 2010 or SP 2013?

Comment: We're using version 2010

Answer (score 0):

You can Create Folders for each team member with may be their name as folder name. Then Apply folder level permission.Each team member will have access to their folders only and they will have to upload their documents to their folder.

1. Create folders for each team member
2. Select the folder , Set unique permission for this folder.Click **Stop Inheriting Permission** .Give the team member and Manager Contribute Rights and remove permission of all other users.

Follow this [Blog](http://plexhosted.com/billing/knowledgebase/271/How-to-manage-permissions-for-a-list-library-folder-or-document-item-SharePoint-2013.html) to create folder level permission.